# Interior, Exterior and Boundary of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

If we denote the general point of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $(x,y)$, determine $\operatorname{Int} A$, $\operatorname{Ext} A$, $\operatorname{Bd} A$

where  $A$ is specified by the condition: $x$ and $y$ are rational.
Since every neighborhood of $(x,y)$ contains points that lie and don't lie in $A$, my conclusion is:$$\operatorname{Int} A=\operatorname{Ext} A=\emptyset$$ and$$\operatorname{Bd} A=\mathbb{R}^2$$Am I wrong?

Comment: What is the metric we are dealing with? Is it the Euclidean?

Comment: I suppose so since my book doesn't say it explicitly

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning for the interior and exterior seems correct. Since any non-empty open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with the Euclidean topology) contains both elements with rational and irrational coordinates, there exist no opens completely in $A$ or outside $A$. Now for the boundary, note that the closure of $A$ is actually $\mathbb{R}^2$, since by the same reasoning every neighborhood of any point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ will contain an element of $A$. So the boundary should be $\mathbb{R}^2-\emptyset=\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Does the metric affect in some way my reasoning?

Comment: I mean if I chose another metric, would it be the same?

Comment: @user220138 The metric does matter. Taking the discrete metric (any subset is open) will give that $A$ is both open and closed. Now clearly the interior and the closure of $A$ will both equal $A$, and hence the boundary will be empty.